# Why won't a second section display in MJML?

Tags: html, mjml

```
<mjml>
  <mj-body>
    <mj-section>
      <mj-column>
        <mj-text align="center">
          This is a header
        </mj-text>
      </mj-column>
    </mj-section>

    <mj-section>
      <mj-column>
        <mj-text align="center">
          Another Header
        </mj-text>
      </mj-column>
    </mj-section>

  </mj-body>
</mjml>
```

For some reason in the above MJML email code, the second `<mj-section>` does not display at all when being viewed in a browser. This also will not display when an image is placed within the section rather than a text element. I have only just discovered the framework today so any information or instruction as to the cause and fix of this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `mj-container` tag. Here is the valid code:

```
<mjml>
  <mj-body>
    <mj-container>
      <mj-section>
        <mj-column>
          <mj-text align="center">
            This is a header
          </mj-text>
        </mj-column>
      </mj-section>

      <mj-section>
        <mj-column>
          <mj-text align="center">
            Another Header
          </mj-text>
        </mj-column>
      </mj-section>
    </mj-container>
  </mj-body>
</mjml>
```

Comment: Thanks. Knew it would be something simple!